# ArrayList sorting using multiple CompareTo to sort attributes in single class

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, compareto

I am trying to to call a method that will sort the ArrayList by goals or by wins. I have a compareTo already inside my FootballClub class which sorts the goals which works. Is there a way for me to have multiple compareTo which sort different attributes such as goals or wins which can be called when my sortGoals or sortWins method is called?

```
public class FootballClub extends SportsClub implements Comparable <FootballClub> {

int wins = 0;
int goals = 0;
int points = 0;

//other methods above 

@Override
public int compareTo(FootballClub o) {
    int compareGoals=((FootballClub)o).getGoals();
    return this.goals-compareGoals;
   }
}
```

Comment: Aside comment: existing `compareTo` method may be improved: 1) casting `o` to `FootballClub` is redundant; 2) it's generally recommended to use `Integer::compare` instead of subtraction even if the integer overflow is unlikely.  So, it could be `public int compareTo(FootballClub fc) { return Integer.compare(this.goals, fc.getGoals()); }`

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for letting me know, did not know that. I will change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any comparator when sorting, compareTo is just what will be used when no comparator is specified (natural comparator for your class):

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-

The natural comparator is also what Java uses internally for String and so on, so that you do not need to specify a comparator every time.
Example: `public final class String implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {`